# How to convert XSD schema to Pyspark schema

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, xsd

I am using databricks/spark-xml jar file for reading XML file.
And I am not able to convert XSD schema file to Pyspark schema.

We can convert json schema to Pyspark schema using

`schema = StructType.fromJson(json_dict_or_list)`

But I am not able to do for XSD schema file.
I was expecting i will be reading XSD file and convert it into pyspark schema.

Answer (score 0):

Databricks has a spark-xml library which includes a nifty little XSDToSchema class (https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/databricks/spark/xml/util/XSDToSchema.scala).

If you have access to spark-shell you could do:

```
spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-xml_2.12:0.16.0
import com.databricks.spark.xml.util.XSDToSchema
XSDToSchema.read(new java.io.File("test.xsd")).prettyJson
```